# How to use gdb mailing list?

Tags: mail

I would like to send an email to gdb mailing list but I cant find on which mail, I have actualy subscribed to mailing list [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/mailing-lists/) but it does not provide info how to send an email to that list any thoughts cheers

Comment: Sorry its not related to ubuntu except Im using it, I was thinking that its ok to ask such question here, my apologies if I was wrong

Comment: tnx @Manoj Sawai